# Laravel project to be accessible from several domains or subdomains

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5

I have a PHP project written on top of the Laravel framework.
My project is accessible with the domain `example.com`, but I want to access it with a sub-domain, like `a.example.com` for example.

What could be the potential implementation, will it lead to having two [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) projects at the same time, or it can be done by means of PHP/Apache?

Answer (score 0):

From official docs for Laravel 5.3

> Route groups may also be used to handle sub-domain routing.
>   Sub-domains may be assigned route parameters just like route URIs,
>   allowing you to capture a portion of the sub-domain for usage in your
>   route or controller. The sub-domain may be specified using the domain
>   key on the group attribute array:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

So you don't need to have two Laravel projects.

**Another suggestion** is to separate front-end and back-end, where your back-end is laravel and front-end will access back-end via APIs.

For APIs laravel 5.3 have official package "Passport".

Passport Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport

Answer (score 0):

[laravel Apis use in a domain to domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GO9b.png)
Help is required for laravel Apis use in a domain to domain